# why is javascript not recognizing my checkbox action

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a few fields.  When the user checks the checkbox, I want the data in 3 of the fields to be set to blank.

Currently, it's not working the way I was hoping.  I am using DOM development to achieve this.

```
(function(){
  getProperties();
})();

function getProperties(){
    axios.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/jsondb/UserProfile").then(function(response) {
         console.log(response)
      //If user checks the box
      if(document.querySelector('input[title="anonymous"]').checked==true){
          document.querySelector('input[title="fname"]').value = " "
          document.querySelector('input[title="lname"]').value = " "
          document.querySelector('input[title="email"]').value = " "
         }else{
          document.querySelector('input[title="fname"]').value = response.data[0].FirstName
          document.querySelector('input[title="lname"]').value = response.data[0].LastName
          document.querySelector('input[title="email"]').value = response.data[0].email
         } 
      
          document.querySelector('input[title="country"]').value = response.data[0].country
          document.querySelector('input[title="office"]').value = response.data[0].Office    
        
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the codepen for more clarity: https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/XWXpoMy

Comment: why is there a url in the code?

Comment: So the user somehow has to check the checkbox before the code somehow triggers render? The code is only triggered when the page has loaded. So if they do anything with the checkbox it will not matter since that code already ran.

Comment: I removed the extra url.  When you say bind events, do you mean add an eventListener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is triggering your function...  you have have getProperties defined to self call itself... but that only happens once...   Consider using the onclick attribute to trigger the getProperties function.

```
<input type="checkbox" title="anonymous" onclick="getProperties()"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to update the inputs when the checkbox is clicked.
In that case you'll need to add an event listener.

```
document.querySelector('input[title="anonymous"]').addEventListener('input',getProperties);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `eventListener` to your checkbox, in order to make updates in the DOM.
Since you are calling the `getProperties()` method at start, and the checbox is not checked at that time, no change occurs `on-load`.

However, if you plan to toggle values in the input box on the basis of the checkbox click, I would suggest moving out the functionality to `clear the values` into a separate function.

You may refer to the updated code-pen: https://codepen.io/idhruvs/pen/vYLdqRo

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind checkbox to an event.

```
$("input[title='anonymous']").change(function() {
    getProperties();
});
```

Comment: Where did you find a jQuery tag/reference in OPs question?